# How to convert Flow<List<T>> to Flow<List<R>>?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm building a repository to retrieve data from a Room database. The Room dao returns a `Flow<List<ObjectDto>>`. However, I need to convert this to `Flow<List<Object>>`. What is the right way to do this?

This is the solution I've come up with. I have a mapper extension `ObjectDto.toObject()`. However, this solution doesn't seem right to me. I have no experience with flows, but collecting and emitting again can't be correct, right?

```
    override fun getObjects(): Flow<List<Object>> {
        return flow {
            objectDao.getObjects().collect { objectDtoList ->
                val objects = objectDtoList.map { it.toObject() }
                emit(objects) }
        }
    }
```

I also found several operators to use on flows without collecting them, but while some of them are able to change the type, I'm not sure how to change the type of a list using these operators.

Comment: Maybe Flow.map is what you're looking for

Comment: @m0skit0 could you give me an example on how to do this?

Comment: Works the same as `List.map`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Flow.map` is what you're looking for

```
override fun getObjects(): Flow<List<Object>> =
    objectDao.getObjects().map { objectDtoList ->
         objectDtoList.map { it.toObject() }
    }
}
```